# MapBox Navigation SDK turn by turn directions not announced

Tags: android, mapbox

I am developing a taxi based Android app in which I am using MapBox Navigation SDK for turn by turn navigation.

But I am facing issue of navigation speech in **Samsung Galaxy S8 and other latest Samsung Galaxy devices** and directions not announced on each turn.

Below is the device configuration in which MapBox Navigation Sound doesn't work:

**Samsung Galaxy S8 configuration:**

**model:** sm-g950u

**Device:** Galaxy s8

**hardware:** REV1.0

**OS:** G950USQU5CRL2 // 8.0.0

**Below is the MapBox Navigation Library which I am importing.**

```
 implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.7.2'
 implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.23.0'
 implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.23.0'
```

Below is a MapBox method for navigation sound but unfortunately it does not announced.

```
.speechAnnouncementListener(new SpeechAnnouncementListener() {
                        @Override
                        public String willVoice(SpeechAnnouncement announcement) {
                            return announcement.announcement();
                        }
                    })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're building with `v0.23.0`? A lot has changed since that release: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md. It's possible you're running into a bug that's already been fixed.

Comment: @riastrad I did update but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to create custom voice instructions, or is the problem that the default instructions are not working on these devices?

Comment: Default instructions are not working on these devices.